# Btle android not call onCharacteristicRead

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I use the JDY-23 module; it has only one characteristic that supports reading and writing.
I created a separate class BtleConnectedClass in which I connect to the device and check the characteristics. This class also has a public void `read(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)` method.
I create the object of this class from the 'BleSelectServiceDialog" class like this

```
bTLegatt=BtleConnectedClass.createInstance(pairedDev,context,udpadeSpinHandler);
  BluetoothGattService service= (BluetoothGattService) spinnerSelectService.getSelectedItem();
                 BluetoothGattCharacteristic read = (BluetoothGattCharacteristic)spinnerSelectRead.getSelectedItem();
                 BluetoothGattCharacteristic write = (BluetoothGattCharacteristic)spinnerSelectWrite.getSelectedItem();
                 bTLegatt.setService(service);
                 bTLegatt.setRead(read);
                 bTLegatt.setWrite(write);
  bTLegatt.read(read); //for read Characteristic
```

The BtleConnectedClass class has a method

```
public void read(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
         Log.d(TAG, "read characteristic: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
         gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
         byte[] value;
         int properties = characteristic.getProperties();
         final BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID);
         int connectedState;
         device = gatt.getDevice();
         manager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
         connectedState = manager.getConnectionState(device, BluetoothProfile.GATT);
         Log.d(TAG, "connectedState " + connectedState);
         if (connectedState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
             if ((properties & PROPERTY_NOTIFY) > 0) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "read: " + "PROPERTY_NOTIFY");
                 value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE;
                 descriptor.setValue(value);
                 Log.d(TAG, "value: " + value.toString());
             } else if ((properties & PROPERTY_INDICATE) > 0) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "read: " + "PROPERTY_INDICATE");
                 value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE;
                 descriptor.setValue(value);

             } else {
                 Log.e(TAG, String.format("ERROR: Characteristic %s does not have notify or indicate property", characteristic.getUuid()));

             }
             gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
             Log.d(TAG, "setCharacteristicNotification: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
             gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);
             Log.d(TAG, "setCharacteristicNotification: "+gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true));
             Log.d(TAG, "descriptor: " + characteristic.getDescriptor(CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID).getUuid().toString());
         }
     }
```

When calling this method in bluetoothGattCallback, even workd the method, with a successful result

```
public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
             super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic parentCharacteristic = descriptor.getCharacteristic();

             if (status != GATT_SUCCESS) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite: failed");

             }
             if (descriptor.getUuid().equals((CHARACTERISTIC_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_DESCRIPTOR_UUID))) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite: " + descriptor.getUuid().toString());
                 if (status == GATT_SUCCESS) {
                     // Check if we were turning notify on or off
                     byte[] value = descriptor.getValue();
                     if (value != null) {
                         if (value[0] != 0) {
                             // Notify set to on, add it to the set of notifying characteristics notifyingCharacteristics.add(parentCharacteristic.getUuid());
                             Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite: Notify set to on");

                         }
                     } else {
                         // Notify was turned off, so remove it from the set of notifying characteristics notifyingCharacteristics.remove(parentCharacteristic.getUuid());
                         Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite: Notify was turned off");
                     }
                 }

             } else {
                 Log.d(TAG, "onDescriptorWrite: " + "// This was a normal descriptor write..");
             }

         }
```

But the public void onCharacteristicRead method is not called when I send data to the bluetooth module.
It turns out that `gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);` Does not work. I've already tried everything.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried manually calling the method

```
 public void readManual(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic){
           characteristic = gatt.getService(service.getUuid()).getCharacteristic(characteristic.getUuid());
           gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
           BluetoothManager manager = (BluetoothManager)context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
          
           Log.d(TAG, "readManual: " + manager.getConnectionState(gatt.getDevice(), BluetoothProfile.GATT));
           Log.d(TAG, "readManual: " +characteristic.getUuid().toString());

       }
```

And then it works

```
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status){
          String value=characteristic.getStringValue(0);
             Log.d(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead: " + value);
         }
```

But this method is never called automatically.

Comment: ***But the onCharacteristicRead method is not called when I send data to the bluetooth module*** - The `onCharacteristicRead` callback is not meant to be called when you send data (with `BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic()`). You should invoke the `BluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic()` method if you want `onCharacteristic` to be called. As a matter of fact, the bluetooth API of Android looks a bit mess to me. So if you are new with android bluetooth programming, especially the BLE, make sure that you understand the API sufficiently.

Comment: When you enable notify, the BLE API will notify you upon any change on the peripheral side with `BluetoothGattCallback.onCharacteristicChanged()` callback. So reading characteristic is not involved in this operation. Consider adding your whole `BluetoothGattCallback` implementation and specify the Android version as well, for further debugging.